# Hiding elements when a textbox empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am unable to hide the `myUL li` elements if the textbox is empty. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onKeyUp="myFunction()" placeholder="Just begin typing.." title="Detail Index">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="/year/2000.html" target="_blank">2000</a></li>
  <li><a href="/year/2001.html" target="_blank">2001</a></li>
  <li><a href="/year/2002.html" target="_blank">2002</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To have the elements hidden when the input is empty you can include the `filter` values in the `if` condition which checks that the user has entered a value.

Also note that the code can be improved and simplified by using unobtrusive event listeners, the `input` event and some ES5 methods:

```js
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', () => {
  let filter = document.querySelector('#myInput').value.toUpperCase();
  document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li').forEach(el => {
    let a = el.querySelector('a'); // gets the first only
    el.style.display = filter && (a.textContent || a.innerText).toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) != -1 ? 'list-item' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
li { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Just begin typing.." title="Detail Index">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="/year/2000.html" target="_blank">2000</a></li>
  <li><a href="/year/2001.html" target="_blank">2001</a></li>
  <li><a href="/year/2002.html" target="_blank">2002</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use querySelector on an ID? And to use two querySelectors/All to get at "#myInput li" ? A simpler version is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529919/295783)

Comment: Very good point. I blindly combined the OP's original two lines without considering any improvements. Updated, thanks

Comment: You probably want to switch between `display: none` and `display: list-item`. I'd rather work with `el.hidden`, though.

Comment: @connexo what is the visual difference between toggling hidden and toggling between display:none and list-item?

Comment: @mplungjan No visual difference, I just happen to prefer using existing API over replicating it.

Comment: .hidden is an existing attribute since IE10 or so

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version

I prefer using getElementById when there is an ID and a compound selector with "#id li"

Also I use the spread operator on the HTMLCollection since older EDGE browsers does not have forEach on an HTMLCollection

It turns out that [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) is supported by IE11 too so here is an even shorter version than my first example at the end

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', e => {
  let input = e.target;
  let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  let li = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li');

  [...li].forEach(el => {
    const a = el.querySelector('a'); // gets the first only
    const text = a.textContent.toUpperCase();
    const show = filter && text.includes(filter);
    el.hidden = !show;
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Just begin typing.." title="Detail Index" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li hidden><a href="/year/2000.html" target="_blank">2000</a></li>
  <li hidden><a href="/year/2001.html" target="_blank">2001</a></li>
  <li hidden><a href="/year/2002.html" target="_blank">2002</a></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) is great to hide stuff when you have a boolean

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', e => {
  let input = e.target;
  let filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  let li = document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li');

  [...li].forEach(el => {
    const a = el.querySelector('a'); // gets the first only
    const text = a.textContent.toUpperCase();
    const show = filter && text.includes(filter);
    el.classList.toggle("hide",!show); 
  });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Just begin typing.." title="Detail Index" autocomplete="off">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li class="hide"><a href="/year/2000.html" target="_blank">2000</a></li>
  <li class="hide"><a href="/year/2001.html" target="_blank">2001</a></li>
  <li class="hide"><a href="/year/2002.html" target="_blank">2002</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd prefer `el.hidden= !(filter && text.includes(filter))`.

Comment: @connexo  I was going to say classList.toggle was more supported, but hidden is actually also supported by IE11 - so see update

Comment: Your first code example still has `.hide` which is not being used. Also no need to spread, browsers that support spreading also support `forEach` on `NodeList`.

Comment: @connexo older EDGE support spread but not forEach on Node Lists